# Android: Custom radiobuttons, is it possible to layer images?

Tags: android, xml, radio-button

I'm making some Custom Android RadioButtons following this tutorial:
http://blog.devminded.com/posts/custom-android-radiobutton

However.. In my project every button is different meaning I have to make very four almost identical images for every button I have.

Is there any way of having a single file for the state_pressed and focus and using a single file for the unique parts?

The code in question is this:

```
<item android:state_checked="false" android:state_focused="true"
    android:drawable="@drawable/red_focused" />
<item android:state_focused="true" android:state_pressed="true"
    android:drawable="@drawable/red_unfocused" />
<item android:state_checked="false"
    android:drawable="@drawable/red_img" />
<item android:state_checked="true"
    android:drawable="@drawable/red_checked" />
```

Thanks for any help!